# Checking multiple mail folders in MobileMail

Tags: ios, mobileme, email

MobileMail checks my IMAP Inbox periodically and that works fine. But I also file emails automatically on the mail server side to some sub-folders of the Inbox. Is it possible to make MobileMail check those too so that I get notifications when new email arrives in those folders?

Comment: What do you mean by MobileMail? The Mail app on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK. No.

MobileMe only has push mail enabled for the Inbox itself, and even then it still doesn't support live updating the way Exchange does. Ie. If I delete the email on MobileMe or even in Apple Mail or Outlook, the iPhone doesn't get notified of the change. It will only pick up the change on the next push notification for an incoming mail.

However, they are actively trying to improve the MobileMe platform, so I foresee this becoming possible in the near future.

Comment: This question is about MobileMail, the iOS Mail application. Sorry for the confusion. The app is called MobileMail internally on iOS.

Comment: @St3fan The same rule applies for all IMAP account testing I have done.